# Android. Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, background-application

I have some trouble while try using broadcast receiver.

Target:
I have three app which will work next schema
1. First - is broadcast receiver app which will write some data to database when it will get a message.
2. Second - is app android which will send some intent with data which must be saved in database.
3. Third - is widget in home screen which will also send some intent with data which must be saved in database.

So, I make three app on eclipse.
1. BroadcastReceiverExample - broadcast receiver it has next files

```
package com.test.receive;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SimpleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "service get started action", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("START","START");

    }

}
```

and the manifest file source

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".receive.SimpleReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="com.test.SIMPLE_TEST_SERVICE"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

also I create App project (BroadcastSenderExample) in Eclipse
and it has file with next sender code

```
package com.test.sender;

import com.test.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class BroadcastSenderExample extends Activity {

    public final static String ACTION="com.test.SIMPLE_TEST_SERVICE";
    public final static String TYPE="type";
    public final static int START=1;
    public final static int STOP=0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnStart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent bcIntent=new Intent(ACTION);
                sendBroadcast(bcIntent);
            }
        });
        btnEnd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEnd);
        btnEnd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent bcIntent=new Intent(ACTION);
                sendBroadcast(bcIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    private Button btnStart=null;
    private Button btnEnd=null;

}
```

Then I install first app on device (and emulator try too), and install second app.
And then second app run intent call nothing happen.

What am I doing wrong?

I make two projects with next code

**Project one wBRReceiver**

File **WBRReceiver.java**

package com.x.brreceiver;

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WBRReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Log.i("THIS IS A TEST RECEIVER","THIS IS A TEST RECEIVER");
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "this is a test receiver", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.x.brreceiver"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver android:name="WBRReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.x.START"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**And project two wBRSender**

File **WBRSenderActivity.java**

```
package com.x.brsender;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class WBRSenderActivity extends Activity {

    private String ACTION_NAME="com.x.START";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent brr=new Intent(ACTION_NAME);
        //I can't use this
        //brr.setClass(this, WBRReceiver.class);
        //Because i just don't have this class in this case
        sendBroadcast(brr);
    }
}
```

And manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.x.brsender"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".WBRSenderActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

And then I install first app onto emulator, and then run second app. And it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the logcat output? There's a very good chance it tells you exactly what's wrong.

Without staring at your code too much, it seems that your manifest is broken. In your receiver, you state the android:name is ".receive.SimpleReceiver"... this value (when starting with a .) is not simply "the part that follows the Android package name) -- though it works out that way most of the time. In your case, your Android package is "com.test" however the package containing your receiver is "com.test.receive.SimpleReceiver" and its Java package is "com.test.receive". Try changing your android:name to "com.test.receive.SimpleReceiver".